# Read all subkeys data and values of windows registry using sql server

Tags: sql-server, registry

I have to read multiple subkeys of a key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the registry using SQL server. **Can anyone suggest on this?**

**For eg. I want to read subkeys of** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XYZ\ABC\PQR\Audit. 
master.sys.xp_instance_regenumvalues is fetching just the data of Audit key and not its subkeys.

Comment: `EXEC master..xp_regenumkeys 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XYZ\ABC\PQR\Audit'`

Comment: xp_regenumkeys return just the subkey names. I want to fetch subkey data and value as well. @JosefZ

Comment: I'd save `xp_regenumkeys` results to a variable (or cursor/temporary table) and then call `xp_regenumvalues` (or `xp_instance_regenumvalues`) iterating previously saved subkeys. I'd suppose that you need to CREATE/ALTER a stored procedure  to  do the task.